# Kivy: Screen containing ScrollView, StackLayout and Labels is all out of place

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, stacklayout

I am trying to have a screen which contains a StackLayout. This StackLayout contains several labels of short to long length. The whole content of the StackLayout should also be scrollable with ScrollView. I tried the setup below, but basically every Label is out of place. I have tried several alternative setups based on my understanding of kivy documentation and of (somewhat) similar questions on the internet, but non of them really worked.

Here is a minimal working version of the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (350, 600)


class RootWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(RootWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.searchButton = Button(text="Search",
                                   size_hint=(1,0.8))
        self.searchButton.bind(on_press=self.search)
        self.add_widget(self.searchButton)
        # some irrelevant code

    def search(self,instance):

        #here some omitted code which grabs some strings from a SQLite db and saves results in src, ingsList and steps

        src = 'Lorem ipsum'
        ingsList = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit amet']
        WMan.transition.direction = 'left'
        WMan.current = 'second'

        # theses should be aligned at center of the screen
        WMan.current_screen.title.add_widget(Label(text=src,
                                                   size_hint=(1,None)))

        WMan.current_screen.ingredients.add_widget(Label(text="Ingredients:",
                                                           text_size=(self.width, None),
                                                           size_hint=(1,None),
                                                           height='30sp'))
        # these should be left aligned
        for i in range(0,len(ingsList)):
            WMan.current_screen.ingredients.add_widget(Label(text=ingsList[i],
                                                                  text_size=(self.width, None),
                                                                  size_hint=(0.9,None),
                                                                  height='20sp'))
        # center aligned
        WMan.current_screen.ingredients.add_widget(Label(text="Steps:",
                                                           text_size=(self.width, None),
                                                           size_hint=(1,None),
                                                           height='30sp'))

        # this should be left aligned (or, ideally, justified)
        steps = "Duis finibus risus tempor nisl scelerisque, quis facilisis augue pretium. Nullam sit amet nibh ex. Pellentesque lobortis eget ipsum a congue. Nunc luctus odio sit amet arcu interdum, id pharetra urna semper. Proin at turpis vel neque facilisis pretium ut sed massa. Phasellus elit diam, elementum at tempus non, eleifend quis libero. Integer convallis tortor eget mattis eleifend."
        WMan.current_screen.ingredients.add_widget(Label(text=steps,
                                                                       text_size=(self.width, None),
                                                                       size_hint=(1,None),
                                                                       pos_hint=(None,None),
                                                                       height='10sp'
                                                                       ))



class SecondWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.title = StackLayout(pos_hint={"x":0.05, "top":0.9},
                                 size_hint = (0.9,0.2))
        self.add_widget(self.title)

        self.ingredients = StackLayout(pos_hint={"x":0.05, "top": 0.8},
                                       size_hint=(0.9,None),
                                       size_hint_y=None,
                                       orientation='lr-tb',
                                       spacing = (0,2))
        self.ingredients.bind(minimum_height = self.ingredients.setter('height'))

        self.scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1,None),
                                 size=(self.width, Window.height),
                                 pos_hint={"x": 0.05, "top":0.8})
        self.scroll.add_widget(self.ingredients)
        self.add_widget(self.scroll)

WMan = ScreenManager()
WMan.add_widget(RootWindow(name='root'))  
WMan.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='second'))

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WMan


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more easily solved by using the `kv` language. Here is a modified version of your code that does what I think you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (350, 600)

class LeftAlignedLabel(Label):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<LeftAlignedLabel>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: '20sp'
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
<SecondWindow>:
    StackLayout:
        id: title_stack
        pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top":0.9}
        size_hint: (0.9,0.2)
        Label:
            id: title
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: self.texture_size[0]
    ScrollView:
        id: scroll
        size_hint: (0.9,0.7)
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "top":0.7}
        StackLayout:
            size_hint: (0.9,None)
            orientation: 'lr-tb'
            spacing: (0,2)
            height: self.minimum_height
            Label:
                text: 'Ingredients:'
                size_hint: (1,None)
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                height: '30sp'
            BoxLayout:
                id: ingredients
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: self.minimum_height
            Label:
                text: 'Steps:'
                size_hint: (1,None)
                height: '30sp'
            Label:
                id: steps
                text_size: (self.width, None)
                size_hint: (1,None)
                height: self.texture_size[1]  # adjusts height according to text
''')


class RootWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.searchButton = Button(text="Search",
                                   size_hint=(1,0.8))
        self.searchButton.bind(on_press=self.search)
        self.add_widget(self.searchButton)
        # some irrelevant code

    def search(self,instance):

        #here some omitted code which grabs some strings from a SQLite db and saves results in src, ingsList and steps

        src = 'Lorem ipsum'
        ingsList = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit amet']

        WMan.transition.direction = 'left'
        WMan.current = 'second'

        # theses should be aligned at center of the screen
        # WMan.current_screen.title.add_widget(Label(text=src,
        #                                            size_hint=(1,None)))
        WMan.current_screen.ids.title.text = src

        # these should be left aligned
        for i in range(0,len(ingsList)):
            WMan.current_screen.ids.ingredients.add_widget(LeftAlignedLabel(text=ingsList[i]))

        # this should be left aligned (or, ideally, justified)
        steps = "Duis finibus risus tempor nisl scelerisque, quis facilisis augue pretium. Nullam sit amet nibh ex. Pellentesque lobortis eget ipsum a congue. Nunc luctus odio sit amet arcu interdum, id pharetra urna semper. Proin at turpis vel neque facilisis pretium ut sed massa. Phasellus elit diam, elementum at tempus non, eleifend quis libero. Integer convallis tortor eget mattis eleifend."
        WMan.current_screen.ids.steps.text = steps


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


WMan = ScreenManager()
WMan.add_widget(RootWindow(name='root'))
WMan.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='second'))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WMan


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The `LeftAlignedLabel` class is used to get the ingredients list left aligned.

Also, using the `kv` language makes it easier to see questionable structures. For example, the title `Label` is the only child of the first `StackLayout`. Generally, if you are not planning to add additional children, a layout with just one child can be replaced by just the child.

Comment: Thank you John. You convinced me to finally move my layout code to a kv file. This worked exactly as intended.